# How to display small size image as large size image without losing the clarity of image in python?

Tags: python-imaging-library

```
image = Image.open('red.jpg')
image1 = image.resize((160,120), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

The original image red.jpg was of dimension 80x60.....
i obtained an image with less clarity or with blurness...
so please specify some methods to increase the clarity of the resized image

Comment: It seems that what you're asking for is impossible.  You can't add meaningful information to the second image (larger) that wasn't there in the first image.  Or am I misunderstanding what you want to do?

Comment: cant we retain the clarity of the small image with the big image

Comment: The small image is made from a certain number of pixels, and the color of each pixel is all the information you have.  Let's imagine that your starting image is very, very small, just one pixel.  Now you want to make a 10x10 image from this pixel.  You can't get anything else but a large 10x10 square that's just the color of this original pixel.  If you start with a larger image, it's the same problem but just for more pixels.